# Winforms CheckedListBox element bound to window title

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I need to create a window for managing open dialogs (hiding, showing, adding new, closing). I want each of the records of a CheckedListBox to be title of a window (`someFormObject.Text`). And I also want to change records if the titles change.

As for now I know I can create a `DataSource` (list of strings) for my `CheckedListBox`:

```
_listRecords = new BindingSource();
checkedListBox1.DataSource = _listRecords;
_listRecords.Add(newForm.Text);
```

But that will make text static - it won't change when the window's title changes. How can I handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way.

You actually need to add the actual `form`, not the `string` to the records (as you pass reference instead of value type).

```
private BindingList<Form> _activeWindows;

// constructor:
checkedListBox1.DataSource = _activeWindows;
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";

// adding new element
_activeWindows.Add(newWindow);
```

Binding will update everything automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another type of collection (like a dictionary) and store the window handle as the key, and the text as the value. When the form's title changes you can find your value and update it.

```
    public Dictionary<IntPtr, string> forms = new Dictionary<IntPtr, string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newForm = new Form();
        newForm.Text = "New Form Text";

        forms.Add(newForm.Handle, newForm.Text);

        //look through our dictionary to find if the form exists
        //if it does, update the value, otherwise add a new entry
        if (forms.Keys.Contains(newForm.Handle))
            forms[newForm.Handle] = newForm.Text;
        else
            forms.Add(newForm.Handle, newForm.Text);

        RefreshDatasource();
    }

    private void RefreshDatasource()
    {
        checkedListBox1.DataSource = forms.ToList();
        checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    }
```